# How to return the_excerpt (without echo)?

Tags: php, excerpt

Hey all, I see that get_the_excerpt() echoes the post excerpt if it is manually set, but not if it is automatically generated (with just the 55 words, for example). [and its use is deprecated]

the_excerpt() on the other hand, echoes directly without giving me a string in return.

Is there a function to return the excerpt of a post in Wordpress, including automatic excerpt if not manually defined, without echoing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure thing my friend, you see, the function "the_excerpt" (located at "WORDPRESSINSTALLDIR/wp-includes/post-template.php") is the one that makes the echo:

```
function the_excerpt() {  
    echo apply_filters('the_excerpt', get_the_excerpt());  
}
```

so, what you want is to use the same function "apply_filters" without the echo:

```
$myexcerpt = apply_filters('the_excerpt', get_the_excerpt());
```

...and there you have your excerpt.

Answer (score 2):

There's also the function [`wp_trim_excerpt()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_trim_excerpt), which will generate and return an excerpt for the current post.

Comment: Thanks, so `wp_trim_excerpt(get_the_excerpt())` would also work for my purpose. However, I ended up going with the apply_filters solution, because I also have [another plugin messing with excerpts](http://www.cnet.ro/wordpress/thumbnailforexcerpts) installed.